# Issue with a strange margin on IE11 - overflow and smooth scroll might be related

Tags: html, css, overflow, margin, smooth-scrolling

I've got tiny problem with a website [plenarto.github.io](https://plenarto.github.io) that bugs me for few last days.

Strange white margin appears on the right side of a website whenever you open it with IE11. It goes all through the website, from the bottom to the top. You can't target it with developer tools, nor add any border to it with:

```
* {
border: solid red 1px;
}
```

White margin causes the website to have additional horizontal scrollbar in the bottom.

Adding overflow-x: hidden to the html and body solves that issue, but then the problem with vertical scrolling appears (I suppose it might be connected with smooth scroll).
When overflow-x: hidden is added, on IE the website can't be scrolled with a mouse wheel at all, and on Chrome all internal links stops working.

I've been trying to find any solution for that for a quite while...

Does anyone know what might be the cause of that strange margin and how to get rid of it without using overflow-x: hidden?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies somewhere in `#projects .main-container`. If you add `overflow: hidden` to this div problem dissapears. Probably margin of one of projects item is overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the elements inside the “Projects” section. In particular the class `project-container`. The whole style is not properly implemented.

Try with this:

```
.project-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you want the shadow back just style the the `img` inside the `div`, not for the `div` itself. Also you might need to adjust the width for the media queries.

Whenever you add a padding, margin, border or shadow to an element with a fixed width it increases the size outside the container, this can be bypassed by adding the display: `inline-block` and `box-sizing: border-box` properties.